# C# Checklistbox Value with Database

Tags: c#, database

My checklist box is generated using a query

```
query = @"SELECT CONTENT
                FROM qBank
                GROUP BY CONTENT
                ORDER BY MIN(CHAP)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        dAdap.Fill(dSet);
        for (int i=0; i < dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            chkList.Items.Add(dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
```

I want to get the values of the checkeditems query the CONTENT/s checked and pass it to the next form. But Im lost on how to do it. I saw using foreach statement, but honestly I cannot come up with the condition.

Comment: first:  your query is incomplete. You are only getting one field you would need at least one more (boolean) for checked/ not-checked

Comment: hmm. that query is to populate the chkList. im just getting the content string and place it to my chkList.Items


I still dont have a query to get the checked items. Since I don't know how to do it.

Comment: ok, I think I understand you better now. You want to extract the checked items values to pass to another form or back to DB (?).
You should show us what your User Interface is. More specifically (show us) what is  chkList is?
we don't even know if you are winforms webforms mvc etc. ?

Comment: ![design view](https://ibb.co/fKNXia)
checklist will populate as soon as the form load
![interface view](https://ibb.co/eBTSGv)
im using winform. when button next is pressed will show a next form that will display the question and the choices (one at a time) based on the content/s selected.

if you cant see the image let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Text = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(); //Text field here
item.Value = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(); //value field here
chkList.Items.Add(item);
```

Try to achieve this, hope you have different text and value fields, if you not have that use same thing into value and text field

Comment: item.Value  , value not available